# Javascript changes variable between caller "methods"

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Given:

```
    function testfunc(i) {

        this.foo = function() {
            i = 2;
            console.log("testfunc.foo before bar: " + i);
            this.bar();
            console.log("testfunc.foo after bar: " + i);
        };

        this.bar = function() {
            i = 3;
            console.log("testfunc.bar: " + i);
        };
    }
    
    var testvar = {
        foo: function() {
            i = 4;
            console.log("testvar.foo before bar: " + i);
            this.bar();
            console.log("testvar.foo after bar: " + i);
        },

        bar: function() {
            i = 5;
            console.log("testvarbar: " + i);
        }
    };
    
    var a = new testfunc();
    var b = Object.create(testvar);
    i = 1;
    a.foo();
    console.log("main: " + i);
    b.foo();
    console.log("main: " + i);
```

The result is:

> "testfunc.foo before bar: 2" scope.html:37
>
> "testfunc.bar: 3" scope.html:44
>
> "testfunc.foo after bar: 3" scope.html:39
>
> "main: 1" scope.html:66
>
> "testvar.foo before bar: 4" scope.html:51
>
> "testvarbar: 5" scope.html:58
>
> "testvar.foo after bar: 5" scope.html:53
>
> "main: 5" scope.html:68

Is it supposed to be like this, that the i variable is inherited from one method/function to another within a javascript object? And does it mean that the only somewhat safe way to instantiate an object in javascript is using "new" on a function, or am I missing the point entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `i` is a global variable (it isn't declared locally, so Javascript just makes it global) so everywhere you're changing it, it's the same variable you're using and modifying.

If you want `i` to be local to a method put `var` in front of it each place you declare it like this:

```
    this.foo = function() {
        var i = 2;
        console.log("testfunc.foo before bar: " + i);
        this.bar();
        console.log("testfunc.foo after bar: " + i);
    };
```

If you want `i` to be property of your object, then reference it with `this.i`.

```
    this.foo = function() {
        this.i = 2;
        console.log("testfunc.foo before bar: " + this.i);
        this.bar();
        console.log("testfunc.foo after bar: " + this.i);
    };
```

If you just reference an undefined variable, then Javascript makes it an implicit global variable that is then available to all code as a single global variable.

Comment: Wow, I've gotten the var keyword backwards, I thought THAT made things global. Thanks!

Comment: @lash -  A `var i;` declaration in the global scope creates a global variable.  A `var i;` declaration in a function scope creates a local variable.  An assignment to `i` without any prior declaration automatically creates a global variable (what you had).  These implicit global variables are considered a bad practice and are even now an error if you put your JS in strict mode (the purpose of strict mode is to avoid bad practices and have the JS engine help tell you about them).

Comment: @lash - Since it looks like maybe you're new here at StackOverflow, I thought I'd mention that the procedure here is that if you get an answer that actually answers your question, you can select it as the best answer by checking the green checkmark to the left of that answer to indicate your question has been answered.  That earns you some reputation points for following the procedure and earns the person who provided the answer some points too.  Reputation points earn you more privileges on the site over time.

Comment: Again many thanks @jfriend00 ! I tried to vote it up, but it wouldn't let me.

Comment: @lash - yeah, you have to earn a little more reputation before you can upvote.  Thanks for doing the checkmark.